# Why doesn't an executable jar acknowledge jars inside it?

Tags: java, jar, executable

I made an executable jar that depends on other jars with the command prompt using the format

```
jar cvfm MyJarName.jar manifest.txt *.class dependentJar1.jar dependentJar2.jar
```

The jar was made properly and everything seemed fine... But when run, it gets runtime errors because it can't find the class files that my project refers to. Exploring the created jar, the other 2 jars that it depends on are in there just as they should be and they are listed in the manifest.mf class path, but for some reason java is dumb and doesn't actually look inside those jars.

When those 2 jars are in the same directory as the owner jar, java is able to find them and it works fine. But I don't want this; I want those jars to actually be INSIDE it. What's the deal? How can I make an executable jar with other jars inside it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use something like [OneJar](http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/) or [jarjar](http://code.google.com/p/jarjar/) (or any of several others) to pack up everything inside of a single jar.

If you're building with Maven you could use the [Maven Shade Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/).

You *could* use a custom classloader like [JarClassLoader](http://www.jdotsoft.com/JarClassLoader.php) that will allow precisely what you want.

Comment: ...Would you mind explaining how to use onejar? Like, for what I want to do, how exactly would I do it? I downloaded it and it looks really complicated

Comment: @Pojo Depends on how you're building; the *easiest* is probably to follow the [Ant example](http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/index.php?page=build-tools&file=ant-example).

Comment: I'm not. Also I just found some directions... I'm doing the command line approach as described by this page: http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/index.php?page=getting-started&file=quickstart

What exactly does it mean by "unjar" in step 3?

Comment: @Pojo It means to extract the jar file; jar xf.

Comment: @Pojo That's something to either ask a new question about, or take up with the package maintainers, I guess. If you start a new question, make sure to include what files *are* there, since it could be something as simple as a changed name without a corresponding documentation change. Or try jarjar, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you could. Maybe it's somehow possible with customized classloader, but not from-the-box. Use maven shade plugin.

Answer (score 0):

If you use an Ant Builder in Eclipse and put the referenced jars in a library accessible to your project, Eclipse will extract the necessary classes and include them in your distributable jar file.